# Catching a swf's outgoing message

Tags: javascript, html, flash, message

Hey there, I currently have something going that gets me a pretty accurate value inside a swf (one I have no control over), but I want even more precision

I know it will sometimes send out data about itself to other locations

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Do you mean sending values from flash to javascript via ExternalInterface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you suspect that it is communicating over the wire, you would want to use a Proxy to monitor incoming and outgoing data.

You could use Charles : http://www.charlesproxy.com/ which has a free trial version.

But you could also use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox with the [AMF Explorer plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/amf-explorer/) which is free.

Cheers